# MySQL repeated accounts in the last X months

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I am trying to extract the repeated accounts of a website DB.
I am able to get a table like this:

```
|email         |_year |_month|
| user1@xy.com |2016  |    09|
| user1@xy.com |2016  |    10|
| user1@xy.com |2016  |    11|
| user2@xy.com |2016  |    11|
```

and I would like to get a table like this:

```
|Num Repeated Acc  |_year |_month|
| 0                |2016  |    09|
| 1                |2016  |    10|
| 1                |2016  |    11|
| 0                |2016  |    12|
```

where repeated accounts are those accounts that appeared in the last month and once (or more than once) in the past 3 months.

Using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(q1.email) AS last,_month,_year FROM 
(SELECT email, max(_month) as _month,max(_year) AS _year FROM
active_accounts GROUP BY email) q1 
GROUP BY q1._month,q1._year;
```

I am able to get how many users appeared for the last time per month. However I would like to filter all those users that appeared this last time but didn't appear within the last 3 months. How could I do that?

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `Num Repeated Acc  for 2016 11 --- 1` is correct?

Comment: yes, for Nov 2016 I have 2 users but only one (user1@xy.com) accessed the website before